# Samarkan Font not support in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

[image]I'm developing one iPhone application and I want to use samarkan font, but it is not working, showing the following error: Unrecognized fon family 'Samarkan'. Please guide me, if anyone have solution.

Comment: can you share font link, so others can check.

Comment: yes please check this link, http://www.dafont.com/samarkan.font

Answer (score 2):

please add the font file to your project and add it under "copy bundle resources" in build phases.[image: see in image]

[image]

Comment: I have already done all the steps, but it's not working. I have tried other fonts, and they are working fine, only 'Samarkan' font is not working.

Comment: but for me its working. you added the file under copy bundle resources as i mentioned in above image..?

Comment: Yes, I added same , but not working, please check image in question with red circle.

Comment: Thanks dude, it is solved . one vote up for your efforts.

Comment: what was the problem..?

Comment: I added following code in AppDelegate.m, for knowing the font name, and it's return me "Samarkan" not 'SAMAN'.
code:
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
    
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
      NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that after installing the font, you link it to your project using `react-native link` and restart the packager using `npm start` or `react-native start`.

If you only like the library, this error would come up. Make sure to restart the packager/server